# If there are Vectors, then why are there Arrays?

Tags: c++

I have always asked this question to myself. I tried to find the answer in the internet but, I just couldn't find what I was really looking for. If the developers made Vectors which can be used easier (according to some people), then what was the use of Arrays(which are generally avoided, according to some people aswell)?

Comment: Why do you feel vectors are 10x better than arrays?  If you only need 100 items, ever, then why pay for the cost of a vector?

Comment: @NathanOliver what are the costs of using a vector?

Comment: First of all what do you mean by `Vectors` and `Arrays` `std::vector` `std::array` or what?

Comment: I too wonder, where did the "10x better" metric came from? Why not 5x, or 50x?

Comment: Unless you are using a custom allocator `std::vector` is going to use `new` or `malloc` to acquire memory.  That costs you big time compared to not dynamically allocating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements stored in an `std::array` can be allocated on the stack as the size is known at compile time and elements of a `std::vector` will be allocated on the heap. This can make a huge performance difference. Or more general, an `std::array` does not need its own memory allocation but an `std::vector` always does.

Comment: @ImmaNoobInProgramming FYI most implementations for `std::string` are a hybrid of `std::array` and `std::vector` as they do small string optimization. The data of small strings is hold within the object and don’t need an additional allocation for the data, large strings do need an additional allocation.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, `array` is used to refer to two distinct kinds of things. One is `std::array`. The other is the built-in array type you get from a declaration like this: `int foo[10];`. This defines an array of 10 integers, named `foo`.

The advice against using an array will (at least usually) refer to the built-in array types. I don't know of anybody who advises against using `std::array` (except for cases where somebody needs a different container such as `std::vector` instead).

It's pretty easy to advise using `std::array` over a built-in array type simply because `std::array` is designed to impose no overhead compared to a built-in array type. In addition, however, `std::array` provides the normal container interface for getting things like the first element of the array, the size of the array, or iterators to the beginning and end so it's easy to apply a standard algorithm to an `std::array`.

Of course, all of these *can* be done with built-in array types as well. The implementation of `std::array` doesn't contain any "magic"--it just provides a standard interface to things you could do on your own. At the same time, it does provide a standard interface, and normally imposes no overhead, so there's rarely a reason to do the job on your own.